Can co-ordinate distance (euclidean distance) comparison be simplified?
Question
I have a target co-ordinate pair (lat, long), and I have a list of other co-ordinate pairs.
The units are in decimal degrees.
I'd like to find the pair closest to the target, not distance itself, so purely comparison.
More precisely, I'd like to know how simple of a calculation can I use / or what the fastest method is?
I need accuracy to the closest 10m and I'd like to not use modules for this.
Initial Solution
Initially, I figured it'd be easy as e.g.
coord_set = [{lat, long}, {..}]

target_lat = 20.1234
target_long = -120.5678

pair1 = abs(target_lat - coord_set[0][lat]) + abs(target_long - coord_set[0][long])
pair2 = abs(..) + abs(..)

if pair1 < pair2:
   closest = coord_set[0]
...

Tangent
The I thought perhaps I could simply compare totals i.e.
total = target_lat + target_long
(total - (pair1[lat] + pair1[long])) > (total - (pair2[lat] + pair2[long]))

But I found that has some issues.
Euclidean Distance
Finally I found that I should use euclidean distance (I don't need Great-circle distance, as these coordiantes are typically less than 2-3 km apart).
I found this SO Answer noting comparisons don't need to be square rooted, since distance isn't needed.
**But then I ask, why even square them? **
Simplifying -
pair1 = ((lat - pair1[lat])**2 + (long - pair1[long])**2)**(1/2)
pair2 = ((lat - pair2[lat])**2 + (long - pair2[long])**2)**(1/2)

To this
pair1 = (lat - pair1[lat])**2 + (long - pair1[long])**2
pair2 = (lat - pair2[lat])**2 + (long - pair2[long])**2

To finally this, which is essentially what I started with
pair1 = (lat - pair1[lat]) + (long - pair1[long])
pair2 = (lat - pair2[lat]) + (long - pair2[long])

Is it because it's a 2D plane?
Or should I use it for better accuracy?
I'm struggling to visualise it on a graph, so I can't figure out why for my problem, I should use Euclidean distance

Think about a right-angled triangle - the hypotenuse is NOT the sum of the other two sides, but the squared hypotenuse is the sum of the squares. Ultimately you will have to square.. However, you can use unsquared distances - and sometimes just either lat or long to rule out points which clearly aren't at minimum distance.

@lastchance Thank you, that adds some clarity, and a good point cutting some calculations with that last sentence (sorry, I'm unable to upvote it, but +1)

There are some mathematical inconsistencies in your reasoning.

I'd like to find the pair closest to the target, not distance itself,
so purely comparison.

Finding the pair of coordinates closest to the target is mathematically the pair that is at the shortest distance from the target. So, it is distance itself.
Square root is a monotone increasing function, so in order to compare distances you don't really need to pass by the square root, indeed.
Thus, your first simplification is mathematically correct, but the second one isn't. As Neil mentioned in the first answer, latitude and longitude are signed values! So, you can't "simplify" by removing the squares.
Here's an example:
target = (0, 0)
pair_1 = (-1, 1)
pair_2 = (1, 1)

Then, the squared distances would be:
squared_distance_pair_1 = (0-(-1))**2 + (0-1)**2 = 1 + 1 = 2
squared_distance_pair_2 = (0-1)**2 + (0-1)**2 = 1 + 1 = 2

So you see that both points are equidistant from the target (the origin in this case). If you draw these points, you would easily see it's true.
But if you inject these values in your second simplification expression:
pair1 = (lat - pair1[lat]) + (long - pair1[long])
pair2 = (lat - pair2[lat]) + (long - pair2[long])

you'll get:
pair1 = (0 - (-1)) + (0 - 1) = 0
pair2 = (0 - 1) + (0 - 1) = -2

which doesn't give you any information about the distance.
In conclusion, you have to compute all distances and find the shortest one. And bear in mind that you may have more than one point at that same shortest distance from your target point:
coords = [(lat, long), ...]
target_lat = 2.0
target_long = -3.0

distances = [(c[0] - target_lat)**2 + (c[1] - target_long)**2 for c in coords]
shortest_distance = min(distances)
closest_pairs = [coords[i] for i, d in enumerate(distances) if d == shortest_distance]

I wrote it this way because you said you didn't want to use any external libraries, but for better performances you could at least use numpy.
Best regards.

Thanks for breaking it down and explaining like that! I'm having some issues correlating signedness and and squaring but that's my own problem, I think I get that since it's two dimensional, I have to square it?
But this does mostly make sense to me, so thank you very much
Could you explain the difference with absoluting? Or is squaring simply faster? Or could it be that absoluting in this case works, but more complex equations it doesn't? Or accuracy? Sorry, my maths knowledge is pretty limited!

Think about the 2D coordinate system, basically draw a cross on a piece of paper and take the point 4 on the x-axis, and the point 3 on the y-axis. To compute the distance between them you need to find the length of the segment connecting them -> so you use the Pythagorean theorem! That length is 5. If you take the absolute values distances with the origin you'll get 7. In 2D we have new angles possible! The euclidian distance comes from here, that''s why sometimes we call it pythagorean distance. In 1D you can use absolute values, because you're on one line, so no other angle than 0 and 180.

(I forgot to say) Thank you for the explanation, that does make sense looking at it that way. You've been very kind, I really appreciate it @7ovana

The main problem with just adding the offset in longitude to the offset in latitude is that these 2 numbers are signed.
Taking the total of the 2 suggest a negative offset in longitude will counteract a positive offset in latitude.
For example if the target is (0,0) then (1,-1) should be some distance away, however if you just take the totals without squaring then these appear to coincide.
You need to use squaring for distances since it correctly highlights that (0,2) is further than (1,1).

That explains the problem I was encountering with the totalling method and gives reason for squaring, thanks! +1

You should definitely install a geodetic library to have precise results for testing: on your use case, you may do a lot of simplifications, or maybe not. It really depends on the required precision, distance, but also on the extreme latitudes (near poles you may not simplify too much), so generic answers are not practical, especially if you look for speed.
Then I would calculate differences of latitude and longitude, multiply both with a factors (depends on latitude and longitude) and do normal Cartesian coordinates (root of sum of squares of each delta coordinate component). In such manner you should have good precision (depending on how precise you select the factors).
The trick is to select the factors, you see maths and details in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Length_of_a_degree (and the two linked article, one for latitude and one for longitude). Possibly just few values and interpolation should be good enough (more items to have more precision, and in any case table look up should be fast, or eventually for extra precision the formula, but it would be slow and probably not needed). For such reason, you must have installed a geodetic library, to quick check the precision. You will be impressed on how precise the results will be with few data.
Note: such method work only on continental scale (better within 10 degrees), but not near poles (really near).

Thank you for this, it definitely gives me a lot to consider if I scale the calculations to bigger areas, especialy in terms of accuracy, and reason to use some libs
